# Simple vs complex user entry functions in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

At this site: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html there is user entry function listed as follows:

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
    (format *query-io* "~%~a: " prompt)  
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (read-line *query-io*))
```

Are there any major advantages of above function as compared to following simpler form:

```
(defun prompt-read2 (prompt)
    (format t "~%~a: " prompt)
    (setf answer (read-line)))
```

Is it recommended to always use `force-output` and `*query-io*` all the time?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the answer to a global variable like that is bad. You should just return the answer and let the caller do what it wants with it. If you do use special (~global) variables, you should put asterisks around the name (`*ANSWER*` instead of `ANSWER`).

`FORCE-OUTPUT` is needed to ensure that the user actually sees the prompt before having to answer. If I run the second version using SBCL in a terminal, the program just freezes to wait for input without saying anything.

`*QUERY-IO*` should be used for querying things from the user, because some environment might want to handle that differently from other output. For example, someone might write a GUI wrapper for your program that turns the queries into graphical dialogs. Or maybe they want to run it as a part of a script, providing the input from a string.

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~%~a: " prompt)  
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))

(defun hello ()
  (format t "~&Hello ~a!~%" (prompt-read "What's your name")))

(defmacro with-input ((input) &body body)
  `(let ((*query-io* (make-two-way-stream (make-string-input-stream ,input)
                                          (make-string-output-stream))))
     ,@body))

(defun test ()
  (with-input ("jkiiski")
    (hello))
  (with-input ("rnso")
    (hello)))
(test)
; Hello jkiiski!
; Hello rnso!
```

**Edit**

A more complex example using SBCLs gray streams.

```
(defclass foo-stream (sb-gray:fundamental-character-input-stream)
  ((output-input-script :initarg :script :accessor foo-stream-script)
   (output-stream :initarg :out :accessor foo-stream-out)
   (current-input :initform nil :accessor foo-stream-current-input)))

(defmethod sb-gray:stream-read-char ((stream foo-stream))
  (with-accessors ((input foo-stream-current-input)
                   (out foo-stream-out)
                   (script foo-stream-script)) stream
    (when (or (null input)
              (not (listen input)))
      (let ((output (string-trim '(#\space #\newline)
                                 (get-output-stream-string out))))
        (setf input (make-string-input-stream
                     (format nil "~a~%"
                             (cdr (assoc output script :test #'string=)))))))
    (read-char input)))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~%~a: " prompt)  
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))

(defun hello ()
  (format t "~&Hello ~a!~%" (prompt-read "What's your name"))
  (format t "~&I'm ~a too!" (prompt-read "How are you"))
  (format t "~&~a~%" (if (string-equal (prompt-read
                                        "Do you want to delete all your files")
                                       "yes")
                         "Deleting all files... (not really)"
                         "Not deleting anything.")))

(defmacro with-input-script ((script) &body body)
  (let ((out-sym (gensym "out")))
    `(let* ((,out-sym (make-string-output-stream))
            (*query-io* (make-two-way-stream
                         (make-instance 'foo-stream
                                        :out ,out-sym
                                        :script ,script)
                         ,out-sym)))
       ,@body)))

(defun test ()
  (with-input-script ('(("What's your name:" . "jkiiski")
                        ("How are you:" . "great")
                        ("Do you want to delete all your files:" . "No")))
    (hello))
  (with-input-script ('(("What's your name:" . "Foo Bar")
                        ("How are you:" . "fine")
                        ("Do you want to delete all your files:" . "Yes")))
    (hello)))

(test)
; Hello jkiiski!
; I'm great too!
; Not deleting anything.
; Hello Foo Bar!
; I'm fine too!
; Deleting all files... (not really)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you code is easy but the first is more clarifying what are you doing:

> *query-io* is a global variable (which you can tell because of the * naming convention for global variables) that contains the input stream
>   connected to the terminal. The return value of prompt-read will be the
>   value of the last form, the call to READ-LINE, which returns the
>   string it read (without the trailing newline.)

This is what they said about *query-io*

And about the streams that you can put there works as follow:

> most other I/O functions also accept T and NIL as stream designators
>   but with a different meaning: as a stream designator, T designates the
>   bidirectional stream *TERMINAL-IO*, while NIL designates
>   *STANDARD-OUTPUT* as an output stream and *STANDARD-INPUT* as an input stream

in this case it seems that this is only pointing to *standard-input* and not to the bidirectional stream t